# Deserializing specific JSON fields into a list of objects in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json-deserialization

For a personal project, I'm trying to deserialize a big Json array into a list of objects, however I repeatedly run into issues when following other guides. I have the following json file:

```
{
  PokemonJSONList : [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "region": "Kanto",
      "name": "Bulbasaur",
      "typeList": [ "Grass", "Poison" ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "region": "Kanto",
      "name": "Ivysaur",
      "typeList": [ "Grass", "Poison" ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "region": "Kanto",
      "name": "Venusaur",
      "typeList": [ "Grass", "Poison" ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "form": "f2",
      "region": "Kalos",
      "name": "Mega Venusaur",
      "typeList": [ "Grass", "Poison" ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "form": "f3",
      "region": "Galar",
      "name": "G-Max Venusaur",
      "typeList": [ "Grass", "Poison" ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "region": "Kanto",
      "name": "Charmander",
      "typeList": [ "Fire" ]
    },
...
    {
      "id": 898,
      "form": "f4",
      "region": "Galar",
      "Legend": "true",
      "name": "Shadow Rider Calyrex",
      "typeList": [ "Psychic", "Grass" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, some json entries have more key-value pairs than others, as this json file is used for more than just this project. I only need the Name, Region, Typelist, and Legend(not shown, as the json file goes on considerably longer) fields. I also have this class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PokemonList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<PokemonOBJ> PokemonJSONList;
}
```

Meant to recieve this json data, and this class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PokemonOBJ : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public List<string> TypeList { get; set; }
    public bool Legend { get; set; }
}
```

To be the base object for storing the data for each entry. However, when trying to serialize the json file as such:

```
string jsonString = @"Assets/JSON/data.json";
    public PokemonList PokemonDB;
PokemonDB = JsonUtility.FromJson<PokemonList>(jsonString);
```

results in a "cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type PokemonList"
tutorials I used showed using PokemonOBJ for FromJson but that results an error in vs itself, and I'm a bit lost here on how to get this working properly, and what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html):

> Only plain classes and structures are supported; classes derived from
> UnityEngine.Object (such as MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject) are
> not.

Comment: This fixed it! Totally missed that before, and that lead me to enough new errors that I think I've got it working. Thank you so much!